# Prevent php code from executing in textarea on save

Tags: php, parsing, content-management-system, textarea

I have an issue with a cms where code inside a textarea is executing when you try to save it. For example, lets say you have a textarea with the following html/php in it.

```
<div class="footer">
    <?php include("assets/footer.php"); ?>
</div>
```

On most servers it works fine and just reads the code as text and saves it perfectly. However, on other servers, it actually parses the php and executes it when you click save. This causes an error and breaks the app. I have tried different methods of opening and reading the file such as fread and file_get_contents and all seem to behave the same. I also tried to wrap the data loaded into the block as CDATA but that did not help either.

Any other ideas what might be causing this and any way around this?

Thank you VERY much in advance for any help on the subject.

This is how the text is saved:

```
$fp = @fopen($fname, "w");

         if ($fp) {
            fwrite($fp, $block);
            fclose($fp);
          }
```

This is how the file is read:

```
if (file_exists($fname)) { 
    $fp = @fopen($fname, "r");

    if (filesize($fname) !== 0) {
        $loadblock = fread($fp, filesize($fname));
        $loadblock = htmlspecialchars($loadblock);
        fclose($fp);
     }  
}
```

Here is the form:

```
<form method = "post" action = "">      
    <textarea  name = "text" ><?php echo $loadblock; ?></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: There is a form around the textarea that save the content inside the textarea into a .html file.

Comment: Sorry, I added the code above.

Comment: This isn't an issue on the behaviour of the server, or on how the PHP is included, or on the textarea itself. How is the POSTed textarea handled?

Comment: Here is how the POST is handled:

$block = stripslashes( $_POST["page"]);

Comment: Still can't figure this out, anyone else have any ideas? It only seems to happen on some servers. Others just save the text area with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ways:

**1) Adding & Stripping Slashes**

```
$loadblock = addslashes($_POST['page']);
$loadblock = stripslashes($loadblock);
```

**2) HTML Entities**

```
$loadblock = htmlentities($loadblock);
```

Those are two simple ways you can do it, this is just so you can understand a basic way or two. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately neither of those worked. It is still parsing the PHP when you submit the form.

Comment: And I'm still an idiot!
At the end of all your php, before the ?> - put `}` and at the end of my other code, before the ?> of it, add `else{`

Comment: Hmm, is this for another post maybe? Doesn't seem to make sense with my question?